# Wordpress Widget Rerun php for each Client

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, plugins

I want to get the client's exact address by getting their IP address, and the code I am currently using in PHP:

```
    $ip  = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? 
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=myAPIKey&ip=$ip";      
    $d = file_get_contents($url);        
    $data = explode(';' , $d);
    $lat = $data['8'];
    $long = $data['9'];
    $city =  $data['6'];
    $state =  $data['5'];
    $country =  $data['4'];
    $address = "$city, $state $country";
```

However, no matter where the person is who goes onto the website, they all get my location. I believe this is to be a caching problem - that the php only runs once. Is there anyway to ensure that this plug-in (or all of them) will be rerun for every client? 
The caching plugin used is: W3TC.

Comment: Have you created an API key for this ipindofb.com service? I notice `myAPIKey` in the URL. Perhaps if you don't supply one it just returns the info for the querying server? _BTW, not sure how reliable that is - it seems to think I live in a town 185 miles away_ :-/

Comment: I used 'myAPIKey' just to replace the actual API key that I have. 
The ip address is supposed to define the location, not the API key, so I don't see how changing it or, even more so, removing it would help.

Comment: Ah well, just a thought - some people do just blindly copy & paste the example from the website without realising they have to change it. Have you tried disabling your cache plugin to see if that's the culprit?